# How return value string is null from an ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How check string value null or not to return JSON result from a controller

I tried but without success so far - can you help me please?

```
public JsonResult Check(string Name)
{
    return Json(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "NULL"));
}
```

This is the jQuery script:

```
//return $.ajax({
//    type: "POST",
//    url: "/Home/Check",
//    //data: "Name",
//    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
//    dataType: "json",
//    success: function (response) {
//        if (response) {
//            alert("not exist");
//        }
//        else {
//            alert("exist");
//        }
//    }
//});
```

If Name NULL the user have alert error

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an exception in the controller when the value is null. (I'm assuming that the FirstOrDefault returns a boolean value (provide more info if it is not the case).

```
public JsonResult Check(string Name) throws Exception
{
    ...
    if(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "NULL"))
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return Json(true);
}
```

This way you can handle the exception in the second part of the response:

```
success: function (response) {
    if (response) {
        alert("exists"); // This part of the code will execute normally
    }
    else {
        alert("not exists"); // When throwing an execption, this part of the code will execute
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Linq extension Any.

Your code would become:

```
public JsonResult Check(string Name)
{
    return Json(db.Users.Any(c => c.Name == "NULL"));
}
```

Also, switch alerts in JS:

```
success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                alert("exists");
            }
            else {
                alert("not exists");
            }
        }
```

Some comments:

1) Do you actually use the value "NULL" (as a string) in the DB, or are you checking for NULL?

2) Seems a small violation of the separation of concerns principle to have the context injected into your controller, consider using a DAL between your controller and context.

L. E.: what is the "Name" param of your method used for?